# Clearing out shared instance in swift while logging out

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a shared instance user profile class which I'm using to maintain the user details throughout the app, now when I log out I want to clear out all the data in this shared instance class. Below is my sample declaration of current class

```
class UserProfile: NSObject {
    static let sharedUserInstance =  UserProfile()
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var userType = UserType.student
    var email: String!
    var zipCode: String!
    var profileImage: UIImage = Constants.defaultProfilePic
    var hobbies: [String]?
    var userPreferences: UserPreferences?
}
```

I would like to clear out all the variables in the shared instance at once. One way to go about would be to declare a clear function and set nil to each object for eg:

```
func clear() {
firstName = nil
lastName = nil
so on...
}
```

Is there any better or easier way to do this so that my `UserProfile.sharedUserInstance` gets resets at once ?

Comment: That's a sign that you probably shouldn't use the singleton pattern here.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sigleton class for the entire project and save user information in that class and at logout time assign nil to that object

```
class Singleton {

private init() {}

static let shared = Singleton()

var userInfo:UserInfo?
}
```

on login just assign user information object to this from your viewController like this

```
Singleton.shared.userInfo = your_object_to_save
```

and on logout just assign it nil value

```
Singleton.shared.userInfo = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

I created a second class called user, which will only be accessed by UserProfile. 
Each UserProfile object has a User instance variable.(I don't know how, but if you can figure out a way to make the User class private to UserProfile, that would be ideal)

In swift, variables can have getters and setters so you can have matching variables in UserProfile and have their getters and setters access the variables in User.

When done this way, you can access the variables in UserProfile without needing any knowledge of the User class.

Then in the UserProfile clear function you can just do `self.user = User()`

---

I reduced your variables down to just first name and last name for a simpler answer.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
}



class UserProfile {
    static var userProfile = UserProfile()
    var user = User()
    var firstName: String? {
        get{return user.firstName}
        set{user.firstName = newValue}
    }
    var lastName: String? {
        get{return user.lastName}
        set{user.lastName = newValue}
    }
    func clear(){
        self.user = User()
    }
}
```